# How to create live streambuilder from sqflite database in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, sqflite, flutter-streambuilder

I have local database of sqflite.
And I had set future list of database by below method.

```
Future<List<Message>> messageList() async {
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await _db!.query('Test',orderBy: 'timestamp DESC',);
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Message(
          inboxId: maps[i]['inboxId'],
          messageId: maps[i]['messageId'],
          sticker: maps[i]['sticker']
      );
    }
    );
  }
```

But I want create stream builder of this database for updating listview every time on CRUD operation ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing that issue, **SQLite** will not work in terms of updating your data with `StreamBuilder`.

If you want this functionality, I recommend you to use **Moor** library for that.

Unfortunately, the moor is not available on pub.dev.

**Note: Moor has been renamed to drift** : https://pub.dev/packages/drift

```
dependencies:
  drift: ^2.2.0
```

Comment: I used sqflite_sqlcipher for encrypt database

Comment: moor_flutter 1.4.0 not available in https://pub.dev/ DISCONTINUED

Comment: You can check out sqlite_wrapper 0.1.1 for reactive use

Comment: will sqlite_wrapper work on sqflite_sqlcipher ?

Comment: I edited the answer, can you check it out?

Comment: Sorry, sqlbrite is not working , i already tried

Comment: I edited the answer, the moor package has been renamed to drift, drift library will solve your issue.

Comment: has drift separate database or Will it work on sqflite-sqlcipher ?

Comment: I don't know about that if you are want to work on streams the best solution to work with drift (old Moor)